# How to get the accurate date from the database on fetch request from react to postgresql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql-9.5, urlfetch

i am fetching data on an react application which is connected to a **postgresql** database  there's a date field in the table when I am getting the data Of that date field On fetch request it will have the previous date from the date I have there in the database  Don't know why is this happening . Any help will be most welcome ,Thanks in advance!

This is what i get in Invoicedate column
[image: This is what i get in Invoicedate column]

This is what I have in the database
[image: This is what I have in the database]

data in database going through this query:-

```
"INSERT INTO  ordertable(invoicedate,invoicenumber,clientname) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING order_id "
```

And Fetching through this query :

```
const getordertable = "SELECT * FROM ordertable ORDER BY order_id DESC ";
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code or sample data as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: how do you know that the data is as per the second image? is that date column a timestamp? could the stored data represent "the end of the day" (being midnight the next day) and hence to humans you need to deduct 1 day because they wish to see it as "during this day". post the query that formed the second image - and don't use images of data please.